# WSo2 EMM root device checking

Tags: android, mdm, wso2-iot

I have a question related to security checking while accessing apps form wso2 emm.I want that if the user have rooted his/her device than he/she will not be allowed  access the appstore .Can this restriction facility be availed through wso2 emm.If yes than how we can achieve this.Any help will really be appreciable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App store is a web app. A user will access the app store using their browser and if they have permission to install a apps on a device they will install it. However, app install operations are sent through WSO2 EMM to the device as operations. For a device to receive operations it has to be enrolled with EMM and rooted devices are not allowed to enroll with EMM. Root detection is available in Android[1].

[1]. https://github.com/wso2/product-emm/blob/master/modules/mobile-agents/android/client/client/src/main/java/org/wso2/emm/agent/api/Root.java

Comment: how to import this above mentioned code in our product so that it will check for the rooted device..